# select from one table and do a lookup into another table and get result in the output

Tags: sql

I have two tables.
Table1 from which I am selecting from

```
Number     Code       Prefix      Area      Date
987654321  333        691         SOF       20170503
876543210  445        661         VAR       20170503
765432110  678        611         BOR       20170503
753357891  333        691         SHU       20170502
667788223  445        661         ZOR       20170502
812567111  678        611         NES       20170501
```

And Table2 which I want to use for lookup

```
Code      Prefix      Type      Terminal
333       691         F         NP
445       661         M         P
678       611         F         P
```

In the output I would like to have

```
Table1.Number     Table1.Code       Table1.Prefix      Table2.Status
987654321         333               691                F
876543210         445               661                M
765432110         678               611                F
753357891         333               691                F
667788223         445               661                M
812567111         678               611                F
```

Basically, for each row in Table1 I want to put status from Table2, where

```
Table1.Code = Table2.Code and Table1.Prefix = Table2.Prefix
```

I don't want to use "Join", so is there any other way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you want to use `join`?  That is the obvious approach.

Comment: As Tab Alleman already has said, in this specific case you can use a correlated sub-query instead.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is to use join, but since you don't want to use join

Option 1

```
select 
    Table1.Number, 
    Table1.Code, 
    Table1.Prefix, 
    Table2.Status
from Table1, Table2
where Table1.Code = Table2.Code
and Table1.Prefix = Table2.Prefix
```

But this is still basicly a join, only shorthand

Option2

```
select 
    Number, 
    Code, 
    Prefix, 
    (
        select Status 
        from Table2 
        where Code = Table1.Code
        and Prefix = Table1.Prefix
    ) as Status
from Table1
```

But this only works if the subquery returns 1 row and i figure this must be way slower

Comment: Slower or not depends on the dbms used. Different products optimize in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

With subquery:

```
SELECT
Number, 
Code, 
Prefix, 
(SELECT Table2.Type 
 FROM Table2 
 WHERE Table1.Code = Table2.Code AND Table1.Prefix=Table2.Prefix
) AS Status
FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Table1.Number, Table1.Code, Table1.Prefix, Table2.Status
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table2.Code = Table1.Code
```

using a join is actually the best solution

you also can make a subquery or use where statement but it's a very bad way to do it

then you can do

```
SELECT Table1.Number, Table1.Code, Table1.Prefix, Table2.Status
FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE Table1.Code = Table2.Code
  AND Table1.Prefix = Table2.Prefix
```

but it's a very bad way to do ... as you want

Comment: @jarlh the second is a "fake" join not a real one but yes it works the same
using a subquery is a disgusting way to do this request. where are also hear to teach good practises

Comment: It's a join, trust me. (An implicit, instead of an explicit join.)

Comment: @jarlh then give a better solution
there is not better solution than a join for this request ...

Comment: I don't say there is a better solution than a join. (And I can't see why OP wants a non-join solution. Seems like a theoretical problem.)

Answer (score -1):

> I don't want to use "Join", so is there any other way to do it?

Yes, if you don't want to use a JOIN, you can use a Subquery.